# How do I change the color of the pixels I choose?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I want to make some parts of the picture black.
How can ı change the color of the boxes that i have chosen to black?

My Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("colors.jpg")
height,width = 720,720
img = cv2.resize(img,(width,height))

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_range = np.array([100,50,50])
upper_range = np.array([150,255,255])

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
erosion = cv2.erode(mask,kernel,iterations = 1)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask = erosion)

#cv2.imshow("Image",img)
#cv2.imshow("Mask",erosion)
cv2.imshow("res",res)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC6qc.jpg)
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXDYD.jpg)

Comment: perhaps you should clarify your question. it's difficult to answer if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python/OpenCV, you can use Numpy to change the color corresponding to the mask pixels.

```
img[mask>0]=(0,0,0)
```

Comment: But it changes all of them. I just want to make some of them black.

Comment: Then you need to modify your mask.

Comment: Can't I just close some places after I mask them?

Comment: You can loop over a list of pixels and set the color for each one using Numpy, `img[y:y+1, x:x+1]=(0,0,0)` for example for each x,y that you want to change to black.